# How to debug query in c# program?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to write query more efficient.

I do not want before the end of the query, the list of data to extract.

```
    var UserTimeLineNews = (from l in _newsService.NewsQuery()
                                where l.UserId == UserId && l.IsActive == true
                                orderby l.CreateDate descending
                                select new UserTimeLine
                                {
                                    EventDate = l.CreateDate,
                                    CreateDate = l.CreateDate,
                                    NewsId = l.NewsId,
                                    TimeLineType = TimeLineType.CreateNews,
                                    Title = l.Title,
                                    Abstract = l.NewsAbstract,
                                    CommentCount = l.CommentCount,
                                    LikeCount = l.LikeCount,
                                    ViewsCount = l.ViewsCount,
                                    Storyteller = l.Storyteller
                                }).AsQueryable();//Take(NumberOfNews).ToList();

        var UserTimeLineLikeNews = (from l in _likeNewsService.LikeNewsQueryable()
                                    where l.UserId == UserId
                                    orderby l.CreateDate descending
                                    select new UserTimeLine
                                    {
                                        EventDate = l.CreateDate,
                                        CreateDate = l.CreateDate,
                                        NewsId = l.NewsId,
                                        TimeLineType = TimeLineType.LikeNews,
                                        Title = l.News.Title,
                                        Abstract = l.News.NewsAbstract,
                                        CommentCount = l.News.CommentCount,
                                        LikeCount = l.News.LikeCount,
                                        ViewsCount = l.News.ViewsCount,
                                        Storyteller = l.News.Storyteller
                                    }).AsQueryable();//Take(NumberOfNews).ToList();

        var UserTimeLineComments = (from l in _commentService.CommentQueryable()
                                    where l.UserId == UserId && l.IsActive == true
                                    orderby l.CreateDate descending
                                    select new UserTimeLine
                                    {
                                        EventDate = l.CreateDate,
                                        CreateDate = l.CreateDate,
                                        NewsId = l.NewsId,
                                        TimeLineType = TimeLineType.Comment,
                                        Title = l.News.Title,
                                        Abstract = l.News.NewsAbstract,
                                        CommentContent = l.Content,
                                        CommentCount = l.News.CommentCount,
                                        LikeCount = l.News.LikeCount,
                                        ViewsCount = l.News.ViewsCount,
                                        Storyteller = l.News.Storyteller
                                    }).AsQueryable();//Take(NumberOfNews).ToList();

        var item = (UserTimeLineNews
            .Union(UserTimeLineLikeNews)
            .Union(UserTimeLineComments))
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.EventDate)
            .Distinct()
            .Take(NumberOfNews)
            .ToList();
```

**After running the following error appears**

**Error:**
The type 'UserTimeLine' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query.
A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Comment: Could you post your _actual_ code, not just pseudo code?

Comment: The original code is written exactly the same way. Just y and z by x are related

Comment: Classes in C# are certainly not declared like you have it.

Answer (score 1):

The first two queries don't initialize the `CommentContent` property. Add that to the initializer in the first two queries (or remove it in the last query) and the final query should work.